# Does upgrading a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra phone from Android 13 to Android 14 decrease the phone's performances?

Tags: performance, android-13, android-14, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I have a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13. Does upgrading a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra phone from Android 13 to Android 14 decrease the phone's performances?

Comment: What "performance" are you interested in (for what purpose you are using the phone that is so "performance" critical)? You own a S23, which has a high-end CPU, so most users will not be able to even push this CPU to it's limit. Therefore it is not clear what performance you are talking about.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, e.g., increased lag when navigating through apps (= sluggish UI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback I received on [Reddit](https://redd.it/17qcc1z), it seems that upgrading a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra phone from Android 13 to Android 14 does not result in a decrease in the phone's performances.